# Find folder of shell commands

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to find out where the folders of Tcl and Tk are located.

For exampe I can run `tclsh` or `tclsh8.6` in the console. This shell command should point to a folder, where I can find the tools, right?

How do I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On Bash you can use

   ```
   command -v <your_file>
   ```

   to find the location of an executable as long as it either a builtin or in `$PATH`. More precisely, `command -v` prints the command that is executed by Bash. If it's a builtin, it will simply print the command since there is no location of a binary. If it's an alias, it will print the alias definition.
2. You may use `whereis`. It prints the location of the binary, source and man pages. From the manpage

   > [...]`whereis` then attempts to locate the desired program in a list of standard Linux places.

   If you need the location of the binary only use

   ```
   whereis -b <your_file>
   ```
3. `locate` is another option. It searches an index database of files on your system and is therefor much faster than `find` which truly searches the file system. The database is normally updated regularly via cronjob(daily?), but an update can be triggered with `updatedb` to keep up with recent changes.
4. Well, `find` of course.

   ```
   find / -name <your_file>
   ```

   though that may take quite some time. If you know the file has to be somewhere in `/usr` or `/opt`, replace the first argument with that or any list of paths to be searched.

Comment: thank you. The installation of a program requires me to specify the directory of tclsh. But as it seems there just seems to be the executable in /usr/bin and an .gz file in /usr/share/man/man1/tclsh.1.gz . Do I need to unpack the directory? Can I do that or do I provide any harm to my system by doing that?

Comment: @Skyy2010 What do you mean with "unpack the direcory"? The .gz file is just the manpage of `tclsh` and of no interest here. Apparently the program you try to install relies on `tclsh`, so the installer asks where to find it. I can't possibly tell what the installer will put where. I'm sure there is an option to install to a different directory, like `/opt`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `type`, which is a built-in in most shells.

```
type tclsh
```

From `help type`:

```
Display information about command type.

For each NAME, indicate how it would be interpreted if used as a
command name.
```

Alternatively, you could use `which`.

```
which tclsh
```

From `man which`:

```
   which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be exe-
   cuted in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  com-
   mands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching
   the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.  It
   does not follow symbolic links.
```